# Maintain / Set Column Descriptions for Write Truncate Scheduled Query

Tags: google-bigquery

**Scenario:** We have a number of scheduled queries that copy data into a project that we use as our centralized data warehouse. These are scheduled queries are configured to run nightly, and are set to WRITE_TRUNCATE.

**Problem:** We added descriptions to the columns in several of our destination tables in order to document them. However, when the scheduled queries ran they removed all of the column descriptions. (Table description was maintained.)

**Desired Outcome:** Is there a way to insert the column descriptions as part of the scheduled queries, or some other way to avoid having these deleted nightly? Or is that simply a limitation of WRITE_TRUNCATE scheduled queries?

I've searched Google & Stack Overflow, and reviewed the documentation, but I can't find any references to table / column descriptions in relation to scheduled queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is instead of using WRITE_TRUNCATE with `SELECT`, you can use:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE( <column_list_with_description>)
AS SELECT ...
```

If you don't want to repeat the column description in every schedule query, you may use:

```sql
DELETE FROM table WHERE true;
INSERT INTO table SELECT ...
```

If the atomacy of the update is required, above query could be written into one MERGE statement like:

```sql
MERGE full_table
USING (
SELECT *
FROM data_updates_table
)
ON FALSE
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN DELETE
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN INSERT ROW
```

Comment: Love the simplicity of the DELETE then INSERT approach. My initial concern was that there may be a scenario where the DELETE statement succeeds but the INSERT statement fails (WRITE_TRUNCATE will only truncate your table if the query succeeds, which minimizes risk). However, when I tested it the entire scheduled query failed and my table was not deleted.

Comment: I don't think this is expected (DELETE not effective when INSERT failed). You should consider the MERGE statement, although harder to write, it guarantee this all or nothing semantics. Updated my answer to include the MERGE solution.

Comment: In my test, the scheduled query would no longer parse (referenced a table that had since been deleted). So that's probably why I observed the all or nothing behavior. Thank you for the additional MERGE solution.